# Any Possible Way To Pass Data From Container to Container Holding View?

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, containers

I know that it is possible to pass Data to a container view but can we also pass data inverse? like press a button on the container view and change something on the view that holds the container view?

I have not found any way of doing this in swift, does someone have experience with it?

[image]

Comment: no, I'am sorry I should have been more concrete, I was asking about how to solve this in swift because nothing I have tried has worked yet.

Comment: One of the answer in the question will answer your question. `https://stackoverflow.com/a/28221039/1215715`